# git - Pulling in another branch's work that has been updated

Tags: git

I and another person have been working on separate branches, however I need some the work of the other users branch.

A few days ago - I used `git merge origin/other-persons-branch` onto my own branch. This was working fine and I have added a few commits ontop since then. However - I have to pull their changes again onto my branch and if I do `git merge origin/other-persons-branch` again it has a big pile of merge conflicts.

I tried a plain rebase (`git rebase origin/other-persons-branch`) just as a test - it has the same pile of merge conflicts as well.

I am wondering if there is a better and/or cleaner way to do this. I was considering reverting the array of commits that was their merge and maybe try merging again. I'm thinking there is a less problematic way of doing this. Any insight would be welcome!

Comment: I doubt there's any simpler way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  One thing--have them merge your changes into their branch if they haven't.  That may help.

Comment: Incase anyone runs into this as well - I ended up just making a new branch based off the other persons branch and cherry-picking all my own commits onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to prefer main branch (typically `master`). Or some main branch which you have to consider as master if you can not ready to put this to master. Let say you have branch `main`.

You begin work by creation a `current` branch:

- `git fetch origin` update the main branch from remote
- `git checkout -b current origin/main` create and switch to branch `current` based on `main` branch

So when you have some work done you put your work with next steps to `main`, (suppose you are in `current` branch):

- `git fetch origin` update the main branch from remote
- `git rebase origin/main` rebase your work on top of main branch
- `git push origin current:main` - put you work in `current` branch to remote `main` branch

Same approach must be used by all team members. Any operation like `amend` with commits and so on may be performed only before rebase and push that commits to remote.